# What are my options for creating a Q&A in Sharepoint, similar to StackExchange?

Tags: discussion-board

I am new to SharePoint and I'm trying to create a simple, intuitive Q&A section on a company intranet page. The section must be simple or it simply won't get used. Basic discussion boards have failed in the past so I am hoping for something with an interface similar to StackExchange that can be driven by email alerts.

The true goal is to allow the user to ask their question under a preset topic, and an email alert goes out to a predetermined group of "experts" notifying them of the question. When an answer has been provided, an email alert notifies the original user.

The idea is that everyone is too busy to monitor a message board and most questions need almost immediate responses. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

The exact solution exists as a site template in SharePoint 2013.

[Communities](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219805%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Otherwise (for SP 2007, 2010 or 2013) you could build a list that holds questions and answers. On that list you place an event receiver (Or workflow) that emails the specified users (could be defined in a list or something). the users then can log in, answer the question and the same event receiver (or workflow) emails the creator of the question.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned this in the original question but unfortunately our intranet is still running SP 2007. Is that list suggestion you made still possible in 2007?

Comment: Event receivers are available in 2007 [example](http://aarebrot.net/blog/2010/08/creating-custom-list-event-receivers-in-sharepoint-2007/)

Comment: +1 for the Communities in SP2013 recommendation